# How do you Calculate the Size of the Exceptional Irreducible Root Systems?

Tags: representation-theory, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

There are three exceptional irreducible root systems $E_6$, $E_7$, and $E_8$ which correspond to the Dynkin diagrams

$$
E_6\; 
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\bullet \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \bullet-\bullet-&\bullet-\bullet-\bullet 
\end{aligned}
\qquad
E_7\;
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\bullet \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \bullet-\bullet-&\bullet-\bullet-\bullet-\bullet
\end{aligned}
\qquad
E_8\;
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\bullet \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \bullet-\bullet-&\bullet-\bullet-\bullet-\bullet-\bullet 
\end{aligned}
$$

and have $72$, $126$, and $240$ roots respectively. Wikipedia provides brief explanations of how to calculate the size of these root systems for [$E_6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)#Roots_of_E6), [$E_7$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E7_(mathematics)#Root_system), and [$E_8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)#Construction), basically saying the roots of each system must look like a vector of some form, and then counting the number of such vectors. But that doesn't really say *why* the roots must have that form, or for the case of $E_6$ and $E_7$ *why* it's a good idea to think of them as embedded in a higher dimensional space. Is there a cleaner way to calculate the size of these root systems? Maybe it would be a good idea to construct $E_8$ and realize $E_6$ and $E_7$ as subsystems of $E_8$ to count their roots? Ideally I'm looking for a method that would work well as a presentation to a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to calculate the cardinality of the set of roots is via the formula $|R|=nh$, where $n$ is the rank and $h$ is the Coxeter number. In the case of a real reflection group, the Coxeter number is the largest degree of a fundamental invariant.

For instance for $E_8$, the Coxeter number is $30$, implying that the number of roots is
$$|R|=8 \cdot 30=240.$$

In practice, one might wish to start with the Dynkin diagram and nothing else, and compute $h$ and the number of roots. Here is one quick way to do that: first, play the numbers game on the Dynkin diagram to find the highest root. See e.g. here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13074/figure-out-the-roots-from-the-dynkin-diagram

Of course, you could use this algorithm for computing *all* the roots, but it's much faster to get the highest root. Then obtain $h$ using the formula
$$m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_n=h-1, \quad \text{where} \quad \phi=m_1\alpha_1+\cdots+m_n \alpha_n$$ is the highest root and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the simple roots.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe this is a poor question since I'm not familiar with the formula $|R| = nh$, but how hard is it to prove that formula? Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @MikePierce My favorite reference for all things having to do with root systems is Bourbaki, *Lie groups and Lie algebras* chapters 4-6. See part (iv) of Proposition 33 of section 11 of chapter 6. It's not that difficult to prove. I am going to edit my answer to indicate how this can be used in practice as well (i.e., to calculate h starting with the Dynkin diagram). It's a neat trick.

Comment: @MikePierce The idea is that you can write down the action of the Coxeter element on the set of roots quite explicitly: there are $n$ orbits each containing $h$ roots. In fact, this is closely related to how Coxeter visualized the root systems: you project the roots onto the *Coxeter plane* to get beautiful pictures.